# Jackson JSON do not wrap attributes of nested object

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I've got following classes:

```
public class Container {
    private String name;
    private Data data;
}

public class Data {
    private Long id;
}
```

When I serialize `Container` class using Jackson I get

```
{"name":"Some name","data":{"id":1}}
```

But I need the result to be:

```
{"name":"Some name","id":1}
```

Is it possible (without adding `Container.getDataId()` method)? If so, how to do it?

---

**update**

I've tried to create custom `JsonSerializer<Data>` but the result was same as before

```
public class JsonDataSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Data> {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JsonDataSerializer.class);

    @Override
    public void serialize(Data value, JsonGenerator jgen, 
            SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {

        Long id = (value.getId() == null) ? 0l : value.getId();
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", id);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
        logger.debug("Data id " + id + " serialized to JSON.");       
    }
}
```

I've also tried to add `@JsonSerialize` annotation above `Data` class, then above getter in `Container` class. As I mentioned before without any success. My serializer is used, logger logs message.

---

**update 2**

When I remove `writeStartObject()` and `writeEndObject()` then no JSON is returnesd, only `HTTP Status 500` error and no exception is thrown except of what I found in debug output.

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.example.DataController@16be8a0]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Can not write a field name, expecting a value; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.example.DataController@16be8a0]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Can not write a field name, expecting a value; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.example.DataController@16be8a0]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Can not write a field name, expecting a value; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
```

Comment: what happens if you skip the writeStartObject() and writeEndObject() lines?

Comment: you should probably just write the value: writeNumber(id)

Comment: Yes, writting using just `writeNumber(id)` worked at least to some case. The output was `"data":1`. But what if I want to serialize more then one attribute in `Data` class? I've tried to add `write*Field` methods with and without `write{Start,End}Object` with no luck

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jackson 1.9 has introduced [`JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation which does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create and register a custom serializer for the Data type.

You can use the @JsonSerialize annotation on the Data class.

Specify a serializer class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyDataSerializer.class)
public class Data {
    ...
}

public static class MyDataSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Data> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Data value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've tried to do what you've written (see updated question), but unfortunately the result is same as before.