# What causes HttpMessageNotWritableException?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

What causes a `HttpMessageNotWritableException`? The documentation just mentions

> in case of conversion errors

Comment: When citing, please include your source. Makes it much easier if everybody knows what your asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about your documentation, but [this one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageNotWritableException.html) says:

> Thrown by HttpMessageConverter implementations when the write method fails.

For an example cause check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983067/jackson-json-do-not-wrap-attributes-of-nested-object).